# Java map creation

Tags: java, maps, slick

So Im making a topdown 2d rpg in slick2d and lwjgl 2, and I wanna make a map, but not just random map, something like this:
[image: An example of a map in a game called Realm of the Mad God]

The blue stuff is water and rivers, the gray in the middle is "the mountains" and such. How could I create such a map design, but a random one through code. If anyone has an idea of how this is done, please tell me, or even link a tutorial if you know a good one.
Thanks.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate for a game dev forum, or r/gamedev. That said, depending on how in-depth you want to go with this, http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/ is a very nice tutorial (with links to many more resources) on this sort of procedural map generation. There are many shortcuts that can shorten implementation, and you may find some ideas here http://pcg.wikidot.com/ .

Answer (score 1):

The map in your screenshot is from [Realm of the Mad God](https://www.realmeye.com/wiki/maps-from-builds-106-123). It was generated from [the url that Chris Mills-Price linked to](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/). There's a [flash demo](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/demo.html) on that page, a complete description of the algorithms used, actionscript [source code](https://github.com/amitp/mapgen2), and [links to Java code](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/game-programming/polygon-map-generation/#source).